# How Can I Change My Intranet's Homepage Page Layout?

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, branding

As part of the branding of our new SP2013-based intranet, I have created a new custom Masterpage and Page Layouts and set this as the default Masterpage.

I have also created a custom Masterpage and Page Layout solely for use with the homepage of our intranet.

For the homepage I have overridden the system Masterpage value via SharePoint Designer 2013 - which worked fine. I now need to change the Page Layout used by the homepage however I can't find any option to do so:

[image: 'Edit Page' Ribbons for Homepage and Sub-page (both in same site collection/site level)]
(both pages are in same site so publishing features is available for both)

I know in SP2010 the workaround was to create a new Page in the site with the desired Masterpage & Page Layout and then to set that page as the site's homepage. However that 'solution' results in a change to the intranet's home URL which I've been told is not acceptable.

My Masterpage and Page Layout are working fine (I can use them on new pages).

So my question is 'how can I set the site's default homepage to use a custom Page Layout?'

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you fix the issue so you can share your solution? Thanks,

Comment: You do not have an option to change page layout for those pages who are under "**Site Pages**" Library. Your Home Page will be in "**Site Pages**" Library.

Answer (score 3):

You have the option in the `Page layouts and site templates page` in `New Page Default Settings`section. Select the page Layout that you need to set as default in `Select the default page layout`

For new subsites,

Write a feature stapler which sets your desired page layout on `default.aspx`, while the web provisioning process.

or

Create a custom web template/site definition that uses your desired page layout by default

Comment: Hi @Falak, thanks for the answer. Your suggestions are correct and I've performed the first steps you've mentioned.

I have clarified my question a bit more. I have a custom masterpage set as you've suggested and I have then overridden it for the home page. I now need to override the page layout used for the home page in the same way but there isn't even a 'page layout' button in the ribbon...

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If the site is not using publishing features, you can not change page layouts or stuff like that

Comment: Hi, I updated with a picture to try and illustrate the problem. Publishing features is definitely on but the 'Page Layout' option in the Page Actions Ribbon box is missing for the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

If this is team site then the default page or home page will not have page layout option available even if you have enable publishing feature. You can create publishing page and set this publishing page to default home page (from SharePoint designer). You will have page layouts option available.

Answer (score 1):

If you activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure for the site collection and then activate the SharePoint Publish feature for the site the option to change the page layout should comes up on the ribbon when your are in edit mode.

If you are working with custom branding let me reccomend this site http://bindtuning.com for some versions the themes already include some pages layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I have enabled the Publishing Infrastructure feature and the options aren't present. Have updated the question to clarify.